# Javascript function out of rule

Tags: javascript

I have function that returns the biggest date from array:

```
 function getResult(){
    var arr=[{Id:540, MeasureDate:"2016-06-27T15:06:47"},
             {Id:541, MeasureDate:"2016-06-27T12:24:39"}];


  title.innerHTML = new Date(Math.max.apply(null, arr.map(function (e){  
         return new Date(e.MeasureDate);
   }))).toISOString();}
```

Here is working [fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/28438/).

When I open the fiddler example above in `chrome` and `IE` I get different results.

Any idea why?

Comment: What results do you get? Please include that in your question.

Comment: Chrome support `innerHTML` ? not `innerHtml`?

Comment: _"the biggest date"_ Do you mean the greatest number; most recent date?

Comment: Without seeing what are getting on Chrome and on IE you maybe having encoding issues?

Comment: What does the title "Javascript function out of rule" have to do with your question?

Comment: IE appears to add offset to the given date. So if you are in pacific time it adds about 7 hours. Is that what you are seeing.

Comment: I think maybe chrome and IE returns different dates formats.

Answer (score 1):

The `Math.max` function assumes that everything in its arguments can be converted to a number.  That isn't necessarily true of a Date (and apparently is screwing up, not surprisingly, in IE).

Does this work:

```
title.innerHTML = new Date(Math.max.apply(null, arr.map(function (e){  
         return new Date(e.MeasureDate).getTime();
   }))).toISOString();
```

Comment: I need to the the latest date.your solution not returns the latest date.

Comment: @Michael -- I'm pretty sure it does.  Why, what is returning for you?

Comment: no, it's return diffrent result in diffrent browsers

Answer (score 1):

One more solution. Doing all steps in a single line is not a good idea in terms of readability.

```
var maxDate = Math.max(...arr.map((e)=> new Date(e.MeasureDate)))
title.innerHTML = new Date(maxDate).toISOString();
```

Answer (score 1):

If requirement is to return date string which is most recent, that is, greatest number, you can use `String.prototype.match()`, `Array.prototype.sort()`

```js
var arr=[{Id:540, MeasureDate:"2016-06-27T15:06:47"},
             {Id:541, MeasureDate:"2016-06-27T12:24:39"}];

function n(d) {
  return d.match(/\d+/g).join("")
}

var res = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return +n(b.MeasureDate) - +n(a.MeasureDate)
})[0].MeasureDate;

document.body.textContent = res;
```

Comment: thank you for answer but I need to convert the result to ISO string